# How to auto scale Kubernetes worker nodes on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

Currently, I am working on AWS, ASG (AutoScale Group) and Kubernetes. In the infra, I created one Kubernetes cluster in which there is one master node and another one is a Worker node.

Now my question in case high traffic volume I used the HPA at pod level but it might also possible that this node is not able to handle all the requests.

So in this case, will ASG will create a new node or not. 
If no then can someone suggest be the best way for horizontal scaling at the node level.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a couple of things:

- Setup [Dynamic scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#as-scaling-types) for your ASG to autoscale based on CloudWatch metrics (CPU, Mem) or your own metrics with your own automation.
- Use the Kubernetes [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) so that it autoscales based on not having enough pod capacity on your nodes.